# Is teleportation plausible?

Tags: science-based, physics, super-powers, mutation

one of my characters can teleport himself and other small objects at will. It looks like something dissolving into dust when it teleports. Could this be particles disassembling and reassembling? Are heere any other scientific explanations for teleportation?

Comment: While this might be a neat-looking special effect, any plausible teleportation mechanism won't look anything like that. Ever.

Comment: Plausible is more a function of good writing than it is worldbuilding. A well written story will make all sorts of straight up impossible things plausible.

Comment: It's plausible, yes. Your body is just a machine and machines can be taken down and reassembled in principal, there is nothing special about life from a mechanical point of view. But please consider how complex a single cell is. The fluid you find within is thick as honey. There is no randomness, it's a near perfect assembly of proteins working together, 
 catalyzing more reactions than you will be able to learn in a decade. We can't even begin to synthesize anything like it from scratch. Now think about what you actually want to accomplish here. It's plausible, but still impossible